# How to cancel edit/disable cached input (of type text) value?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, autocomplete, textinput

I have an input of type `text`, from which I have already entered value `1234` 

it has been saved in cache as shown below.

[image]

The **problem** here is that, it is extremely frustrating to select the textbox in the next row.

**Is there a way to not to display that `12334` (highlighted in the screenshot) from ever being displayed through HTML markup or javascript?**

Comment: I did not change the title to "How to disable `Autocomplete` because there might be other people who are unaware of `Autocomplete` attribute option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [@John](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592328/how-to-cancel-edit-disable-cached-input-of-type-text-value/1592348#1592348) pointed out, on modern browsers you can use the [HTML5 valid](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-autocomplete-attribute) `autocomplete` attribute, in your screenshot I see many textboxes, if you want to disable autocompletion on the whole form you can set this attribute directly at the [`form`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#attr-form-autocomplete) element:

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" autocomplete="off"
  action="http://www.example.com/form.action">
[...]
</form>
```

More info:

- [How to Turn Off Form Autocompletion](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion)

Comment: @CMS: John had it right but I wanted to apply it globally to all text input controls.  Applying `autocomplete` to the form completely disabled them all as I intended.  Thanks

Answer (score 7):

[`<input type="text" name="input" autocomplete="off" />`](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/switch-off-autocomplete/)

Answer (score 1):

To apply this to all input controls, write the code below (using jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=text], input[type=password]').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
});
```